# Profile picture in Careers?

Tags: support, status-deferred, profile-page, stack-overflow-jobs, gravatar

I am unable to change my profile picture on the Careers site, just like I can do on all other sites on the StackExchange network. When I click on "Change picture", it just redirects me to http://gravatar.com.

It looks like only a Gravatar can be used on the Careers site, as opposed to all other sites where a normal picture can be uploaded and used (and also synchronized across the whole network together with the user profile).

Is it really so? Does having a profile picture on Career really require a Gravatar (while all other sites don't)? If yes, why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For now, Careers does require Gravatar to change your profile picture. Allowing for uploaded photos is something that's on our list to do in the future and something we certainly want to do, but not coming in the short term just yet.

Comment: Then it should be [meta-tag:status-deferred].

Comment: @FrancescoMenzani thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

So to work around this for now an option would be to:

- head over to https://en.gravatar.com/site/login and register there with the same email address you use on stackoverflow for login
- confirm your mail address on gravatar
- upload an avatar image
- wait 5 minutes
- head to your stackoverflow profile
- select "Edit Profile & Settings"
- select "change picture" below your current profile picture
- choose the (hopefully now available) gravatar option