# My photo doesn't appear in my CV

Tags: bug, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs

While my photo appears everywhere else on Stack Overflow, when you view my CV all you get is the generic photo filler:

[image]

I cannot find a way to add the photo. A bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes - I was also curious about this. I noticed that in the edit CV that there is a checkbox to display Gravatar but this doesn't appear to come through?

Comment: I did notice that it appeared when I looked at the cv link from a browser that wasn't logged into SO - although I did also add an additional Gravatt email address - the SO address already had a pic

Comment: I tried a new incognito window in a new browser. Didn't help

Answer (score 3):

This photo is only available through Gravatar at this time. It uses the email connected to your CV in the "edit cv" section. A similar question has been answered here: [Profile picture in Careers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303962/profile-picture-in-careers/303969#303969)

We will allow for directly uploaded images with the rollout of the Developer Story, but not the CV at this time.